# SAS: Why does ODS LISTING CLOSE prevent graph export?

Tags: sas

I am running SAS 9.4 on Windows.

If I submit

```
/*ods listing close;*/

filename grafout "C:\output\sastest.png"; 
goptions reset=goptions device=png gsfname=grafout;

proc gchart data=sashelp.class;
   where sex="F";
   vbar age / sumvar=weight type=mean subgroup=age 
              nolegend discrete;
run; 
quit;
```

the file `sastest.png` is exported to the `C:\output` folder.  However, if I place an `ods listing close;` statement at the top of the code, the graph is no longer exported.

Apparently, the [listing](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/odsug/67921/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1lyhxs0ue101in1snowd4cdd15q.htm) destination is more than

> an ODS destination that produces traditional SAS output (monospace
>   format).

It is even more confusing because listing is turned off by default:

> Beginning with SAS 9.3, by default, in the Windowing environment with
>   the Windows and UNIX operating systems, the LISTING destination is
>   closed and the HTML destination is open.

Why would the `ods listing close;` statement prevent the graph from exporting?

Comment: When you close the listing destination is the HTML destination still on?

Comment: are you running in Base SAS, SAS Studio or Enteprise Guide?

Comment: I am using Base SAS with the Enhanced Editor.  The HTML destination is still on as it has never been turned off.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because the `ods listing` destination is what is causing your graph to be exported via `gsfname`.  I suspect you will find that it is indeed on before you run the code with it commented out (if it is indeed saving the file).

`ODS HTML` uses a different method to define where graphics should be exported rather than `goptions`; it uses the `gpath=` to define the path to the file, and the `name` option on the plot to define the name of the file.  It is in fact "exporting" the file every time you run this - just not to a useful location (see in your log; it uses the default gpath, probably a temp location, and the default filename, the name of the proc).

```
ods listing close;
ods html gpath="c:\temp" ;
proc gchart data=sashelp.class;
   where sex="F";
   vbar age / sumvar=weight type=mean subgroup=age 
              nolegend discrete name="sastest";
run; 
quit;
```

Your listing destination may or may not be off by default depending on your system's settings as defined by your administrator and/or other options changed during your session.

See [Controlling Where Your Output Is Stored](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/graphref/67881/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n014ro62pa3xu0n165t2qpffbmiv.htm) for more information about specifying how to save SAS/GRAPH files in different destinations.